# Find the visible area of overlapping polygons inside a polygon in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math, 2d

I want to find the "visible" area of multiple overlapping polygons.

Let's say I have a Polygon `polygonA` and let the area be 100%

```
List<Vector2> polygonA; // points CW
```

[image]

Now I have another Polygon Inside `polygonA`  which is `polygon1`(green) and its area is easy to calculate for now Let say the area of `polygon1` is `area_p1` %

```
List<vector2> polygon1; // points CW
```

[image]

Now I have another polygon `polygon2`(red) inside `polygonA` that overlaps `polygon1` so now the area of `polygon1` is changed. for now, the area% of red is easy to calculate but then some other polygon will overlap red polygon and it keeps going on.

```
List<vector2> polygon2; // red
```

[image]

So now how do I calculate the area % of visible color inside the `polygonA`.

I think a [Clipper.cs](https://github.com/PyMesh/Clipper/blob/master/C%23/clipper_library/clipper.cs) could help but I can't find a way to figure it out in unity.

Comment: Clipper seems like a good start. If that fails for you, you could also consider using a forward-from-camera raycast grid to gauge the percentage -- if it hits green (as not obstructed by higher z-index red), it would add to the area size.

Comment: I solved it by casting `x` evenly distributed rays inside the polygon and then calculating the density of each color. So I get % of each colored polygon.